# Manifest File for legacy program

Tags: manifest

I have a legacy VB6 application which has stopped working, I believe because the name.exe.local no longer works in Win11 and I'm told I need a manifest file to get the application to use a dll in the same folder as the application.  This dll is not registered because its name clashes with a different version which is registered in SysWoW64.
Can anyone provide a short manifest that does this?

Do I need a manifest for the dll as well as the exe?

I've read many descriptions of manifest files and they are all unclear, incomplete, inapplicable or quite unintelligible and I'm left pulling out what's left of my hair as nothing seems to work.

Many thanks
Ian